# How to find the largest number(s) in a list of elements, possibly non-unique?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Here is my program,

```
item_no = []
max_no = 0
for i in range(5):
    input_no = int(input("Enter an item number: "))
    item_no.append(input_no)
for no in item_no:
    if no > max_no:
       max_no = no
high = item_no.index(max_no)
print (item_no[high])
```

Example input: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 8]`

Example output: `8`

How can I change my program to output the same highest numbers in an array?

Expected output: `[8, 8]`

Comment: Band indent at line 8

Comment: You can use Dictionary to store the maximum number and its count as item_no = {}, if you max is different then original in item_no, reinitialize it and add that item and add count =1

Comment: ("Band" probably is a misspelling for "Bad")

Comment: @tripleee Indeed. bulls-eye!

Comment: As answers show, it's more Pythonic to do it with list comprehensions, rather than loops. But if you use loops to iterate over the list, a style tip: don't use the same variable name `i` both for indices `i in range(5)` then also for items/values: `for i in item_no`. Better to do `for no in item_no`

Comment: Strictly your question was *"How to find the largest number(s) in a list of elements, possibly non-unique?"*

Comment: Yes, that would more or less be my question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just get the maximum using `max` and then its `count` and combine the two in a list-comprehension.

```
item_no = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]

max_no = max(item_no)
highest = [max_no for _ in range(item_no.count(max_no))]
print(highest)  # -> [8, 8]
```

Note that this will return a list of a single item in case your maximum value appears only once.

---

A solution closer to your current programming style would be the following:

```
item_no = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
max_no = 0  # Note 1 
for i in item_no:
    if i > max_no:
        max_no = i
        high = [i]
    elif i == max_no:
        high.append(i)
```

with the same results as above of course.

Notes

1. I am assuming that you are dealing with N* (*1, 2, ...*) numbers only. If that is not the case, initializing with `-math.inf` should be used instead.

---

**Note that the second code snippet is less efficient than the first by quite a margin. Python allows you to be more efficient than these explicit, fortran-like loops and it is more efficient itself when you use it properly.**

Comment: Actually, I would love to use the first code, but since this part of my school project, I am not allowed to use inbuilt functions, therefore I need to use the second code.

Comment: @user11206537 I kinda saw this coming. Knowing what a better way would be is still of some value. Have fun!

Comment: One last question, how do you find the index of the result (high) in item_no?

Comment: You might want to start with a smaller number than `0`.

Comment: @user11206537 To get the index as well, you can modify the code slightly and use `enumerate` on `item_no`. As you loop through, store the index in a 2nd list as you do for the max. Take a look at [this](https://repl.it/repls/BlaringDarkblueDegree)

Comment: @EricDuminil importing `math.inf` and using that seems like an overkill for this. I will leave that to the OP. He might have to deal with natural number lists only. For the ones seeking a better solution, they can use the first snippet which does not have such shortcomings.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python--does `high` in the second solution need to be defined before the loop if you want to print the result after?

Comment: @Drew Yes, you're right; if `item_no[0] == 0`, the code crashes as `high` isn't defined when reaching `high.append(i)`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I understand the desire to use a loop and express the algorithm in a more "verbose" way but you really don't need `max_no`: just use `high[0]` (and initialize it as `high = [0]`).

Answer (score 21):

You can do it even shorter:

```
item_no = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
#compute once - use many times
max_item = max(item_no)
print(item_no.count(max_item) * [max_item])
```

**Output:**

```
[8, 8]
```

Comment: This is [the fastest out of the SO answers provided](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/219826). It however can be faster.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `list` comprehension for that task following way:

```
numbers = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
maxnumbers = [i for i in numbers if i==max(numbers)]
print(*maxnumbers,sep=',')
```

output:

```
8,8
```

`*` operator in `print` is used to unpack values, `sep` is used to inform `print` what seperator to use: `,` in this case.

EDIT: If you want to get indices of biggest value and call `max` only once then do:

```
numbers = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
biggest = max(numbers)
positions = [inx for inx,i in enumerate(numbers) if i==biggest]
print(*positions,sep=',')
```

Output:

```
3,4
```

As you might check `numbers[3]` is equal to `biggest` and `numbers[4]` is equal to `biggest`.

Comment: note that your solution calls `max` a total of `len(numbers)` times. Storing it outside the list and then using that would be better.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I assume the Python interpreter optimizes this, no?

Comment: @user1717828 No it does not.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, Oh man, I didn't believe this so I tested it out.  `python -m timeit "numbers = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]; max_number = max(numbers); maxnumbers = [i for i in numbers if i==max_number]"` is twice as fast as when the max calculation is in the comprehension.  I've gotten very spoiled from using languages with compilers.

Comment: @user1717828 And you should expect this difference to skyrocket with larger lists. Try it with `numbers = [random.randint(0, 500) for _ in range(10000)]`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Count the occurrence of max number
2. iterate over the list to print the max number for the range of the count (1)

**Hence**:

```
item_no = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
counter = item_no.count(max(item_no))      # 2
print([max(item_no) for x in range(counter)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[8, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be solved in one line, by finding an item which is equal to the maximum value:
To improve performance store max in var
 Mvalue=max(item_no)
`[i for i in item_no if i==Mvalue]`

Comment: How do you find the index of the result in item_no?

Comment: By using enumerate function, we can get index position: [i for i, val in enumerate(item_no) if val in result]

Comment: But isn't `max` called n times? Not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better if we evaluate the `max` in the array and its `count` in one iteration

```
def maxs(iterable):
    max = None
    count = 0
    for index, value in enumerate(iterable):
        if index == 0 or value >= max:
            if value != max:
                count = 0
            max = value
            count += 1
    return count * [max]


print (maxs([5, 6, 7, 8, 8]))   # [8, 8]
print (maxs([3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 0])) # [5, 5, 5]
print (maxs([])) # []
```

Give it a Try!!

Comment: @user11206537 Did you measure and compared the efficiency among the solutions. Can you share with us?

Comment: This kind of solution was the one that was actually needed as a part of my school project and my teacher thought of it as a very efficient solution. This code is also written along the lines of my current programming style, which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: FYI, this [has the second worst performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/219826) of the answers I timed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no possible way to find all max numbers with just a single line **BUT** it will kinda work with this first of all we will sort the list in ascending then do this

```
yourList = [7,7,76,4,54,4,5,234,5,56,7,234,34,234,234]

yourList.sort()
ind = yourList.index(max(yourList))
for i in range(ind,ind+(len(yourList)-ind)):
    print(yourList[i])
```

in this basically we will get the index of the first max number then we will subtract it by the lenght of the list and we will get how many indexes to plus to get all the max digits

**OR**

there is one another way to do it in this way

```
lis = [1,2,3,12,12,1,12,3,4,5,6,12, 12]
count = lis.count(max(lis))
loop = [print(max(lis), end=" ") for i in range(count)]
```

in this way we will get how many times the max number has occurred in the list and print it that many time

Comment: That only prints the max, not the list containing the possibly repeated instances of the max, as requested in the question.

Comment: I made the program to print all the max numbers so be happy :)

Comment: Much better. It's less efficient than other solutions, requiring quadratic time (for sorting) instead of linear time, but you're presenting an interesting alternative and simple solution.

Comment: If you want to make the syntax more compact, you can make the range equivalently like this: `range(ind,len(yourList))`. And you can also replace the loop altogether by a slice: `print(yourList[ind:])` will create a slice with the elements in `yourList` from `ind` to the end.

Comment: I have added another way to do it. So, check it out if it can help you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do without using inbuilt function and stick to your way then below is useful

```
item_no = [0,5,6,2,6,5,6,7,8,1,2,8]
max_no = 0
list = []
for no in item_no:
    if no==max_no:
         list.append(no)  #append the list with the new number
    elif no > max_no:
       max_no = no
       list=[no]         # reset the list with new highest number
print(list)--->output[8,8]
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use nested list comprehensions. Check this out.

```
numbers = [5,6,7,8,8]
maxlist = [num for num in numbers if True not in [True for i in numbers if i > num]]
```

> Output : maxlist = [8,8]